# How to stop execution of all the Testcase in a suite if Suite run mode is found as N,That is read from Excel

Tags: testng

Hi while I'm running my code i'm able to read the Run mode as N from excel and system is throwing new SkippException. But still after thorwing a skippException for SuiteB it's going and executing all The Test cases in SuiteB. 
I Want if skippException is accured in @beforesuite Method , system stop executing all the Testcase of that suite

I have three class in my SuiteB

TestSuiteBase

TestCaseB1

TestCaseB2

```
    package com.qtpselenium.suiteB;

    import org.testng.SkipException;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

    import com.qtpselenium.base.TestBase;
    import com.qtpselenium.util.TestUtil;

    public class TestSuiteBase extends TestBase{

        @BeforeSuite
        public void checksuiteskip(){

            try {
                //Initialize method of Test BASE Class to Initialize the logs and all the excel files
                Initialize();
                 App_Logs.debug("checking run mode of SuiteB");
                if( !TestUtil.isSuiterunnable(suitexlsx, "suiteB")){

                   App_Logs.debug("Run mode for suiteB is N");
                   throw new SkipException("Run mode for suiiteB is N");

               }




            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    }

******************TestcaseB1****
package com.qtpselenium.suiteB;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestCaseB1 extends TestSuiteBase{

    @Test(dependsOnMethods="com.qtpselenium.suiteB.TestSuiteBase.checksuiteskip")
    public void TestcaseB1(){


        System.out.println("We are in Test case B1");

    }

}
************************TestcaseB2**********

package com.qtpselenium.suiteB;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestCaseB2 extends TestSuiteBase{


    @Test(dependsOnMethods="com.qtpselenium.suiteB.TestSuiteBase.checksuiteskip")
    public void TestcaseB2(){


        System.out.println("We are in Test case B2");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, after you threw a `SkipException` you are also catching the exception.
Change your `beforeSuite` to something like below. That should fix your problem

```
@BeforeSuite
public void checksuiteskip(){
    //Initialize method of Test BASE Class to Initialize the logs and all the excel files
    Initialize();
     App_Logs.debug("checking run mode of SuiteB");
    if( !TestUtil.isSuiterunnable(suitexlsx, "suiteB")){

       App_Logs.debug("Run mode for suiteB is N");
       throw new SkipException("Run mode for suiiteB is N");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is changed and finally code is as given below it's working fine to skip the complete suite if the run mode of suite is N.

```
package com.qtpselenium.suiteC;

import org.testng.SkipException;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

import com.qtpselenium.base.TestBase;
import com.qtpselenium.util.TestUtil;

public class TestSuiteBase extends TestBase{


    @BeforeSuite
    public void checksuiteskip(){

        try {
            //Initialize method of Test BASE Class to Initialize the logs and all the excel files
            Initialize();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

             App_Logs.debug("checking run mode of SuiteC");
            if( !TestUtil.isSuiterunnable(suitexlsx, "suiteC")){

               App_Logs.debug("Run mode for suiteC is N");
               throw new SkipException("Run mode for suiiteC is N");

              }else

                   App_Logs.debug("Run mode for SuiteC is Y");     

    }
}
```